# throw Exception java

Tags: java, exception

I got below code but I do not understand why it prints B. Also Can you explain?:

throw Math.random() > 0.5 ?new MyException(): new  RuntimeException();

code:

```
public class MyException extends RuntimeException {

}


public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
        method1();
    }catch(MyException ne){
        System.out.print("A");
    }

  }

  public static void method1() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
        throw Math.random() > 0.5 ?new MyException(): new  RuntimeException(); 
    } catch (RuntimeException re){
        System.out.print("B");
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Did you try to debug it ?

Answer (score 1):

To begin with,

I'd like to point out, for the sake of clarity, that the piece of code

`throw Math.random() > 0.5 ?new MyException(): new  RuntimeException();` is what is called as an inline form of the `if-statement`, written using the ternary operator `?`.

So, essentially,

`throw Math.random() > 0.5 ?new MyException(): new  RuntimeException();`

is the same as

```
if(Math.random() > 0.5){
  throw new MyException();
} else{
  throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

With that out of the way, let's focus on the flow of the program:-

1. The `main` method calls `method1` in a `try` block.
2. The invocation of `method1` opens its own `try` block.
3. The invocation of `Math.random()` returns a decimal value between 0 and 1; each invocation returning a value most possibly different than the one in the previous invocation.
4. So, a `MyException` object is thrown when the `Math.random()` invocation returns a value greater than `0.5`. Else, a `RuntimeException` object is thrown.
5. As the `MyException` class extends `RuntimeException`, in both cases of the random value being greater than 0.5 or not, the `catch` clause can handle both the exceptions. This is because the `catch` clause can catch all instances of `RuntimeException`, **as well as all its sub-types.**

Reference from the official Java tutorials available [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html):

> The system considers it a match if the thrown object can legally be assigned to the exception handler's argument.

6. The Exception object thrown is caught in the `catch` block of the `method1` invocation. And this prints "B".
7. The control of execution terminates at the end of this `catch` block and the program flow never reaches the calling method, the `main` method in this case. Hence, the "A" is never printed.

I hope this clarifies the various points involved.

Answer (score 0):

`method1` throws either `MyException` or `RuntimeException` depending on whether the random number returned by `Math.random()` is higher than `0.5` or not.

It always prints `B`, since regardless of whether `MyException` or `RuntimeException` was thrown, both will be caught by the catch block that catches `RuntimeException` and prints `B` (since `MyException` is a sub-class of `RuntimeException`).

Answer (score 0):

In method1(), you catch all RuntimeException and print "B".
On the other hand, MyException extends RuntimeException in your code.

So, all MyException or RuntimeException are catched by the catch block and print 'B'

You have 'A' never printed because the catch block in method1 handle the exception by catching it. You can rethrow the exception to main method by adding at the end of catch block of method1 the statement `throw re;`